# Understanding temperature drop within throttling processes

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, energy-conservation

I am studying a particular throttling process (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isenthalpic_process, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect): cryogenic flow going through an orifice (please see below)

[image]

Experimental measurements of both static upstream and downstream pressures $p_1$ and $p_2$ yield a pressure drop $\Delta P_{12} = p_1 - p_2 >0$. Same occurs with upstream and downstream temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ (so $\Delta T_{12} = T_1 - T_2 >0$).

**I want to explain the temperature drop $\Delta T$ based on just classical thermodynamics, using the concept of enthalpy.**

Taking a control volume way upstream and another downstream we have $H_u = U_u + P_uV_u$ and $H_d = U_d + P_dV_d$ respectively. Besides, I made the assumption that the volume upstream and downstream is the same given that the expansion caused by the formation of bubbles is negligible way downstream

**Enthalpy is conserved** so it follows that

\begin{equation*}
    H_1 = U_1 + P_1 V = U_2 + P_2 V = H_2
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \Rightarrow \Delta U_{21} = \Delta P_{12} V \neq 0 
\end{equation*}

At this stage I made another assumption: the internal energy is a function only of temperature. Hence

\begin{equation*}
    \Delta U_{21} = \Delta P_{12} V \neq 0 \Rightarrow \Delta T_{12} \neq 0
\end{equation*}

But here's the problem: $\Delta P_{12} V > 0$ so $\Delta U_{21} > 0$. But this cannot be, as it implies $T_{12} >0$ rather than $T_{12} < 0$.

What am I missing?

I am not taking into account the kinetic energy due to the flow, this might need to be incorporated.

Comment: You should be using a single control volume encompassing the orifice disc.  The change in H from inlet to outlet of the cv should be zero for the stream.

Comment: Hi Chester. I arrived essentially at the same equation, $\Delta U_{21} = \Delta P_{12} V \neq 0$, but now 1 and 2 mean inlet and outlet of the new cv.

Comment: U is not just a function of temperature; there is a phase change.

Comment: Let me look at $\Delta U_{21}$ in more detail. The equation I derived, $\Delta U_{21} = \Delta P_{12} V  = W$ is the first law of thermodynamics for the system (given that $Q = 0$). $W$ is the work done on the cv inlet minus the work done on the cv outlet

Comment: In other words,  how can we incorporate phase change contribution to $\Delta U_{21}$ ? Latent heat?

Answer (score 0):

To analyze this change, you should work directly with enthalpy.  For the exit liquid, $H_L=C_P(T_2-T_1)$.  For the exit vapor, $H_V=C_P(T_2-T_1)+\lambda (P_2)$ where $\lambda$ is the heat of vaporization at P2.  These are the exit enthalpies per unit mass.

So if X represents the final mass fraction vapor, $$(1-X)H_L+XH_V=0$$,together with $$T_2=T_2(P_2)$$, where $P_2$ is the equilibrium vapor pressure at temperature $T_2$.